# twitteroauth connection returns http_code 0

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

```
require_once('oauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');


    if (CONSUMER_KEY === '' || CONSUMER_SECRET === '') {
        echo 'You need a consumer key and secret to test the sample code. Get one from <a href="https://twitter.com/apps">https://twitter.com/apps</a>';
        exit;
    }

    /* Start session and load library. */
    session_start();

    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

    echo $connection->http_code; // it returns 0
```

The same code works in another hosting and returns http_code 200 . What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason of the problem, curl command inside the twitteroauth library doesnt work because outgoing connections are disabled in that hosting

Answer (score 1):

Http Code 0 generally means it is either a TIME_OUT or you are not able to connect to the server

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an http code of 0.

What happens if you `echo $connection`? What does that return? Http code of 0 means you'll need to check twitter oauth docs.

Comment: I made a var_dump of $connection in both hostings, they look the same with the exception of a whole bunch of properties returned in the hosting which works which arent in the other  ["http_header"]
 { ["cache_control"]
 ["content_length"]
 ["content_type"]
 ["last_modified"]
 ["pragma"]
 ["status"]
 ["x_connection_hash"]
 ["x_transaction"]
 ["x_ua_compatible"]

Comment: So it's just returning the header? There are no errors or responses attached? What is in the header ['status']?

Comment: the curl command inside the twitteroauth library is not connecting to the host, but I dont know why. It doesnt connect to any host, even curl is enabled in the hosting